# So how to use single xib in multiple devices like iPhone , iPad .......

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xib, universal

When we upload ipa , what we need universal or iPhone mode.

I put iPhone mode and upload in store it rejected due to ipad design is not correct.

So how to use single xib in multiple devices like iPhone , iPad .......

Comment: Use Size-Classes and Auto-layout feature of Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your project for universal devices.
If you are creating your screens with auto layout and autoresize that it should work for all devices include ipad.

If you are creating screens with Coding then use mathematical calculations for give perfect frame for and UI element.

I recommend auto layout and autoresizing to create one xib universal.